# How can I update data entries in multiple rows using triggers in phpmyadmin

Tags: plsql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables -

**input**

- value(INT)
- ID(INT)

**source**

- S_ID(INT)
- S_Qty(INT)

**destination**

- D_ID(INT)
- D_Qty(INT)

Now I want to create a AFTER INSERT **Trigger** on input table.

***For example*** if I insert 100 in ***value*** & 2 in ***ID*** from table **input**

then a trigger should be fired that increments 100 in **S_Qty** where **S_ID=ID (i.e.2)** from table **source**

and simultaneously decrements 100 in **D_Qty** where **D_ID=ID (i.e.2)** from table **destination**

PS - Assume I have stored some values in both **source** and **destination** tables

I have used the following query -

```
DELIMITER //   
CREATE TRIGGER update_input    
AFTER INSERT ON input    
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN     
DECLARE I,V,D,S INT;    
SELECT value INTO V FROM input;    
SELECT ID INTO I FROM input;    
SELECT D_Qty INTO D FROM destination WHERE D_ID = I;    
UPDATE destination    
SET D_Qty = D + V WHERE D_ID = I;    
SELECT S_Qty INTO S FROM source WHERE S_ID = I;    
UPDATE source    
SET S_Qty = S - V WHERE S_ID = I;    
DELETE FROM input;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER update_input 
AFTER INSERT ON input FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

UPDATE source
SET S_Qty = S_Qty + value
WHERE S_ID = ID;

UPDATE destination
SET D_Qty = D_Qty - value
WHERE D_ID = ID;

END; // 
DELIMITER ;

Comment: hey @StanislavL check this out

Comment: You can use NEW. UPDATE source SET S_Qty = S_Qty + NEW.value WHERE S_ID = NEW.ID. Your trigger looks fine.

Comment: @StanislavL it shows an error - check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: Are you entering this in the "Add trigger" dialog or directly in the SQL tab?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch In my PMA there is no tab for trigger inspite of having everything updated so i am directly entering the trigger program in the SQL tab of "input" table. The trigger works fine but the functionality which i require doent work on multiple rows.
I tried loops using CURSOR but it shows error - check your manual..
I cant uderstand where have i lost.